# Origin of responses for Kaddish

Tags: kaddish, nuschaot, nusach-ashkenaz

I have noticed in some siddurim that there are pesukim interspersed before kaddish and between sections from תתקבַל onwards. For those unaware of this practice, it may be found on pg. 58 of this edition of the [Siddur Sefat Emet](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Heidenheim-Sefat-Emet-1906-French-HB43492.pdf) printed for the French community.

While I have heard that these additions post-date the Rishonim, I have heard this without a source. What is the source of these additions?

Answer (score 3):

[Rabbi Shmuel Yitzchak Gelbard](http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=80655) says this is mentioned some earlier Siddurim such as פראג רע"ט ורע"ו;הנאו שע"ו ועוד. He says it is unclear who established this Minhag, however Sidur R' Shabsi in the Hakdama mentions based on the Tur 56 which mentions that we say V'Ata Yigdal Na since it is similar to Yisgadal therefore we say a Pasuk that is similar to what the Chazan is saying in Kaddish.

> לא ברור מי הנהיג אמירת הפסוקים. רבי שבתי סופר מחבר הסידור "סידור ר'
>   שבתי"(שע"ו)כותב בהקדמה לסידור: "ומאחר שכתב הטור (סי' נו) שנהגו לומר
>   ועתה יגדל נא, לפי שהוא לשון יתגדל, שאומר הש"ץ, לכן נוהגין שבכל חרוז
>   מהקדיש שמתחיל הש"ץ, אומרים הצבור בקשה המתחלת מעין התחלת הש"ץ, כמו
>   יתברך קבל ברחמים וכו' וכן בכל חרוז כידוע".

Comment: I was in the middle of writing that! Anyway, the abbreviations are years of printing, and it is worth noting that he later says that the Arizal was against saying them - which would mean that they were already being said, so at the end of the period of the Rishonim they were already customary.

Comment: @Yishai: The question was not asking whether it should be done, it was asking for the source of those who do. If one reads the link they can see that there are those who hold it is improper.

Comment: The question speculated that the custom post-dates the Rishonim. The Arizal's opposition demonstrates the practice existed at the end of the time of the Rishonim (which just precedes the Arizal). I wasn't make a point about whether or not they should be said.